# Durandal child router's activeItem is not changing unless I bind router to a view

Tags: javascript, durandal, single-page-application, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I have a child router setup for one of my viewModels using durandal. However, I can't read router's activeModule when the router is navigating to the second child route unless I also compose a view corresponding to the child route. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Below is my code:

**Parent View Model:**

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function (router, app, ko) {

  var childRouter = router.createChildRouter().makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels/mytest', fromParent: true }).map([
    { route: 'first', title: 'First', moduleId: 'first', nav: true },
    { route: 'second', title: 'Second', moduleId: 'second', nav: true }
  ]).buildNavigationModel();

  return {
    router: childRouter,
    displayName: 'mytest',
    activeModule: ko.computed(function () {
      if (childRouter.activeItem()) {
        return childRouter.activeItem().__moduleId__;
      }
    }),

    activate: function () {
      // Activation code goes here
    },
    canReuseForRoute: function () {
      return false;
    }
  };
});
```

**Parent View:**

```
<section>

  <h2 data-bind="html: displayName"></h2>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
    <li>
      <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: title"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!--<div data-bind="router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }"></div>-->
  <div data-bind="html: activeModule"></div>

</section>
```

The child view models and views are pretty boring. However, if I uncomment the commented line above, then I am seeing the expected results in the next div. Otherwise I just always see the first module only regardless of whether I clicked on first or second.

Comment: What route/s are you hitting? If you debug in the `router.activateRoute` method, and then through to the child router's `loadUrl` method, do any of the `routePattern` handlers match your route?

Comment: I am hitting the expected routes correctly. The loadUrl method also gets the right URL, but when when loadUrl calls the callback to queue the instruction, the isProcessing() observable returns true for the second route.